# Javascript loops and values

Tags: javascript

My book says something and I'm not entirely sure what it means. It says that to make sure a loop executes properly, you need to include some code to change the value of the conditional expression?
What does that mean? Is that correct? I may be reading it wrong but when you have a basic Javascript loop like

```
 if(contactsCount > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < contactsCount; i = i + 1){

           var item = object[i],
               name = item.name,
               email = item.email;
           target.innerHTML += '<p><a href=mailto:' + email + '">' + name + '</a>!</p>;
}
}
})();
```

Surely you aren't changing any values to make it work? I'm new to this so I'm kind of clueless.

Comment: There is no loop in your code?!

Comment: Woops, I must've deleted it somehow. Either way it was just an example I was using in response to the books statement..i'll update it

Comment: A while or for loop has a condition, like `for (var i=0; i<10; i++)`. If you don't update the value if `i` in the `for` statement, you need to update it somewhere inside the loop, otherwise the loop will just continue infinitely.

Comment: If an `if` statement only contains one instruction, you can put it on the same line; if there are several instructions to be executed conditionally, then you wrap them together in `{ }`, either on the same line or on multiple lines. This also works for `if ... else ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...you need to include some code to change the value of the conditional expression? What does that mean?

That this is a bad idea:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    doSomething(i);
}
```

Why? Because the loop will never end. `i`'s value is never changed. Endless loops are a classic form of bug.

So what the book is saying is that you *must* provide for a way for the loop condition (`i < 10`) to change (e.g., by modifying `i`'s value).

A bit of a tangent, but:

Sometimes you see loops where the condition seemingly **can't** change, e.g.:

```
while (true) {
    // ...
}
```

If you find yourself reaching for something like that, stop yourself and try to find a better way. There are very rare use cases for the above, they look like this:

```
while (true) {
    doThis();
    doThat();
    if (someCondition) {
        break;
    }
    doAnotherThing();
}
```

...so in that case, the controlling condition is actually in the middle, and the one in the looping statement itself isn't really the condition. This is almost always poor practice, but in **very rare situations** they can be the right thing to do.

---

> It also says that you can have other statements on the same line as the "if statement", is that right?

Yes, it is. JavaScript doesn't care about lines **at all** (except when it's doing a form of error-correction for you called Automatic Semicolon Insertion; then lines matter because linebreaks stand in for semicolons as part of the error-correction algorithm). All of these are valid and they all do the same thing:

```
// 1
if (a < b) {
    alert("a is less than b");
    foo();
}
// 2
if (a < b) { alert("a is less than b"); foo(); }
// 3
if (a < b)
{
    alert("a is less than b");
    foo();
}
// 4
if (a < b)
{ alert("a is less than b");
  foo; }
```

Because JavaScript doesn't care about lines at all, they're a matter of style.

By far, the most common style for the above is #1.

Separately, if you have just a single *statement* in the control-flow statement's body, the block (the `{...}`) is optional. These do the same thing:

```
// 1
if (a < b) {
    alert("a is less than b");
}
// 2
if (a < b) 
    alert("a is less than b");
// 3
if (a < b) alert("a is less than b");
```

So using `{...}` for a single statement in the body is also, technically, a matter of style. In practice, however, always using blocks leads to fewer bugs in your code. If you leave off the blocks, it ***will*** eventually bite you when you add a second statement and forget to add a block:

```
if (a < b) 
    alert("a is less than b");
    foo();
```

In the above, `foo()` is **always called**, because it's not in the body of the `if`. That code does this:

```
if (a < b) {
    alert("a is less than b");
}
foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for all that information, wow! So the book is correct then? It is necessary to change the value of the condition expression to make the loop work?

Comment: @user3247128: Yes, the book is correct: You *must* provide a way for the condition expression's value to be changed.

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate your help. Is it also possible that you can have other statements on the same line as the "if statement"? I've never seen it done I don't believe.

Comment: @user3247128: Sorry, I'd missed that you asked a second question in your question. (On SO, it's best to ask **one** question/question.) I've added a second answer above.

Answer (score -1):

In a for loop you should really use the (i++) shorthand but the way your doing it (i=i+1) will work fine as well.

Since I don't have your full source code here is an example...

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dp8gz0L6/2/)

//JAVASCRIPT

```
//animals array
var animals = ['cat','dog','fish','bird','tiger'];

//loop through the animals array
for (i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){
    console.log(animals[i]);
}
```